# portable backup device options

Tags: backup, flash

I need a suggestion for an alternative type of backup device to replace tape drive

Answer (score 1):

How much data do you want to back up?  External hard drives are the obvious choice, if one drive isn't enough, you can easily get enclosures that hold 4 drives, [e.g. these ones.](http://www.startech.com/category/parts/data-storage/external-enclosures/multiple-drive/list.aspx)  The title of your post says portable and you can also get external tape drives.  Those would typically be SCSI, however, not eSATA.